# What are my options for keeping a Swift app on my iPhone without paying for the Developer Program?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing an app for personal use using Swift 5 and XCode 14.3.

However, If I run it on my iPhone for "testing", it is only available for a few days. Is there a way to keep it there for longer, without having to rebuild it from XCode each time, and without having to pay for the Apple Developer Program?

Note that I don't care and never will about publishing it on the App Store.

Thanks!

Comment: No. Without a paid membership you will need to reinstall every few days